# How to use liquibase cmd with db2 ssl connection?

Tags: jdbc, db2, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, db2-woc

I'm trying to run liquibase update command using

```
liquibase --driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" --changeLogFile="masterchangelog.xml " --url="jdbc:db2://localhost:60001/SMDINTDB:retrieveMessageFromServerOnGetMessage=true;sslConnection=true;"  --username="" --password="" --classpath=/home/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc4.jar validate
```

But I'm getting following error. Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue? How I can specify the location of certs ?

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.26.14] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

Comment: Insufficient information. Are you connecting to Db2-LUW *on premises* (or Db2-warehouse-on-cloud) ? EDIT your question to specify which jre you are using for liquibase, and whether you configured that jre for SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several pre-requisites exist for *on-premises* Db2-LUW SSL connectivity with jdbc.
liquibase works correctly with SSL connections to on-premises Db2-LUW, if all the prerequisite configuration completed successfully. Here are some tips.

- the target Db2-LUW instance has to be already configured for SSL as per IBM Db2 documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0025241.html). If you are using a cloud based Db2 service from IBM then this is already done for you, although you may need to use the IBM supplied root cert on the client side.
- your client side JRE needs to be configured per IBM's Db2-LUW documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0024688.html). I use the IBM JRE (as supplied with the Db2-LUW server) for liquibase.
- for on-premises Db2-LUW your client side needs the java keystore created, and the server's certificate imported into it (`keytool -importcert -file /your/path/to/server_certificate ...` ).
- for your specific error, for on-premises Db2-LUW you might try additional options in the connection string to tell the JRE how to access the client side keystore into which you already imported the server certificate. Specifically `sslTrustStoreLocation=/path/to/.keystore;sslTrustStorePassword=whatever;` . Note that I did not need these options if using Db2-on-cloud (liquibase worked correctly with SSL to Db2-on-cloud once I added DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt to my keystore (although even that may be unnecessary) , but I did not try Db2-warehouse-on-cloud as I don't use that service.

Comment: Thanks It resolved the issue....I used this command to extract certificate                            
 `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias myalias -file server.arm -keystore mynewdbclient.jks`